# How do I delete typed character (previous character) in QScintilla PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

I know that a method of deleting can be `self.qsci.cut()` and I know in a different language you can use the `DeleteBack()` method, but how can I remove a typed character `event.text()` or just simply remove the previous character in PyQt5. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SendScintilla` provides the interface to scintilla commands:

```
editor = Qsci.QsciScintilla()
# ...
editor.SendScintilla(Qsci.QsciCommand.DeleteBack)
```